# Struct inside struct and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to load a txt file into memory but is not going right in line 
Video->client[cont].name = name;

ps: the txt client is like this

```
txt:
1 name1
2 name2
3 name3
```

and the code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Client
{
    int number;
    char *name;
};

struct Loan
{
    int number;
    Client *client;
};

void check_error(FILE *arquivo)
{
    if(arquivo==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error to open file!");
        exit(0);
    }
}

void load_client(Loan *video)
{
    FILE *arquivo;
    arquivo=fopen("clientes.txt","rt");
    check_error(arquivo);
    int num,cont=0;
    char name[30];
    while(!feof(arquivo))
    {
    fscanf(arquivo,"%d %s " ,&num,&name); 
    video->client[cont].number=num;
    video->client[cont].name=name; //this part give error!!
    cont++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        printf("%d %s\n",video->client[i].number, video->client[i].name);
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
}

int main()
{
    Loan *video=(Loan*)malloc(20*sizeof(Loan));
    video->client=(Client*)malloc(20*sizeof(Client));
    video->client->name=(char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    load_client(video);
    return 0;
}
```

please somebody help me,
ps: sorry about my inglish!

Comment: Please tag the language in question.

Comment: 1. This is no C++. This is C. 2. [don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858). 3. `scanf()` is hard to use correctly, and you failed to do so, so use something else (i. e. `fgets()`, or on Unix, `getline()`) instead.

Comment: What is the error are you getting?

Comment: Furthermore, [`while (!feof(f))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).

Comment: but if i use while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF, how can i get int from txt? however i use fgets() i cant put name[] in video->client[cont]->name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main()`, you are creating 20 clients using following line:

`video->client=(Client*)malloc(20*sizeof(Client));`

So the next line should allocate memory for 20 client names. That is, following line should be in loop with access to each client as client[i]:

`video->client->name=(char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));`

Comment: like this? for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
       video->cliente[i].nome=(char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char)); 
    }

Comment: Yes. And then, in `load_client()` use `strcpy()` instead of `video->client[cont].name=name`

Comment: ty very much, i change i use fgets(video->client[cont].name,50,arquivo);